# How export data using sqoop to Microsoft Sql Table with auto increment id?

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hiveql, sqoop

I have one table on `Microsoft Sql` with field **ID** set auto increment on.

I would like export data from `hadoop` to this `sql` table.

I Created a `hiveql` table to mirror the `sql` table and
I tried set null value on the **Id** column that is auto increment on `sql` but did not work.

There is some argument or some way to do this?

```sh
    sqoop export \
    --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://<sqlserverhost>:<sqlserver port>;database=<sqlserver database> \
    --username="";
    --password="" 
    --table "MYTABLE"  
    --catalog"" 
    -- columns "ID, NAME, VALUE1, VALE2"\
    -- verbose \
```

Comment: Could you post the complete command you tried, this appears to be only a portion of it!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to omit the **autoincrement** column?, in `mysql` it works very well,
maybe `SQL Server` does the same.

In my example I have created an auto increment table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     topic CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     hits CHAR(30) NOT NULL
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I have this data in a file

```sql
Didar,sqoop,30
Rahul,scala,120
myself,cca175,180
Nikita,spark,80
Mithun,spark,1
```

and the `sqoop export`

```sh
sqoop export \
--connect jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_export \
--username root \
--password cloudera \
--export-dir /user/cloudera/files/user.csv \
--table users \
--columns "name, topic, hits" \
--outdir /home/cloudera/outdir \
--bindir /home/cloudera/bindir
```

**the result**

```sql
+----+--------+--------+------+
| id | name   | topic  | hits |
+----+--------+--------+------+
|  1 | Didar  | sqoop  | 30   |
|  2 | Rahul  | scala  | 120  |
|  3 | myself | cca175 | 180  |
|  4 | Mithun | spark  | 1    |
|  5 | Nikita | spark  | 80   |
+----+--------+--------+------+
```